# calculating dates in excel to return specific date

Tags: excel, date

I have dates of all my purchases in  one column, amounts in another column, all purchases up to the 22nd of month are due on the 10th of the following month.
I want excel to create a list of purchases due each 10th of the month!
anybody have a formula?

Comment: You really should show us some example data, what you have tried so far and possibly the desired output. That will make helping you a lot easier

Comment: i tried this formula =IF(D2>DATEVALUE("dd22"), "=DATE(YEAR(D3),MONTH(D3)+2,10)", "=DATE(YEAR(D3),MONTH(D3)+1,10)") and got #value

Comment: agreed - show some sample data and the expected output would help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

`=EOMONTH(D3-22,1)+10`

...so if `D3` contains the date `22-Oct-2017` that will return `10-Nov-2017`, but if you change `D3` to `23-Oct-2017` then `10-Dec-2017` will result